# Create React App not working on node 18 LTS version

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, create-react-app, npm-install

Hi I am trying to npx create-react-app myapp on my terminal but it starts to execute but always hangs up on random node module but the operation can be terminated by ctrl c but the main issue is when I try to install the same node module on which it hangs up it gets install seperately with success but when trying to run cra again it hangs on another node modules I have lates npm version 8 also and 9 also and having node 18 also and 19 also....  And I have installed the create-react-app version of 5.0.10
Please help me I m stuck in this... Cra is creating the main error I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't look into this in depth but at a glance there does currently seem to be quite a few [issues](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues) with CRA regarding compatibility with node 18.
What I would recommend is to use [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/) instead to build your apps, it's faster and often preferred over CRA nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with Node 18.18 but was able to run CRA once I did `npm i create-react-app`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -6):

Go to your project's folder and run the following command;

```
npm install create-react-app
```

This will install the "create-react-app" package in your project's local "node_modules" folder. Then you can create a new React app using the "create-react-app" command in your project's folder.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem, and it doesn't address the issue of Node 18 at all.